# Extract last occurence of a word from a long string in bash

Tags: bash

I have a long string with multiple occurrences of same word like: "key:value" . I want to extract last occurrence of this word from the string in bash. Can anyone please help me to achieve it in bash.

My string would be like :

```
asaadfssffkey:valueaaddsdgfggfkey:valueadadfsfsffggg
```

And, I tried extract substring in bash : `${parameter:offset:length}` , but this will not be generic because offset will always not be the same.

And my expected output will be the last occurrence of a word => key:value
I am getting input from executing jira changelog rest api , so it will have details in following format :

```
{"items":[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":"val4","key5":"val5","key":"val"}]}
```

and there will be multiple occurrences of `items` available , I want to extract last occurrence of `"key":"val"` available in last set of `"items"`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you install tools like `jq` which is meant to parse JSON with syntax awareness? Provide a valid JSON to use with `jq`

Comment: As I mentioned, the long string is part of executing jira changelog rest api , so there will be multiple list "items":[ {}, {} ] and the result is a part of single string , so I need to extract a particular "key:val" pair which is available in last "items" list.

Comment: Python would be great for this.  Assuming it is all in one string, multiple items, multiple key:value pairs.  Split the line on "items", keep only the last one.  Then split on `,`, keep only the last one.  Some cleanup and voila, key:value.  hum or bash, reverse the string, take the first `".+":".+"`  and reverse for result?

Comment: yeah @Nic3500 , I am able to do it using python. Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution:

```
grep items < input_file |  tail -1 | rev | cut -d',' -f1  |  rev |  tr -d ']'
```

Demo :

```
$echo "items":[{..},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":"val4","key5":"val5","key":"val"}] | grep items |  tail -1 | rev | cut -d',' -f1  |  rev |  tr -d ']'
key:val
```